# Building an array with reference to another object by ID parameter

Tags: javascript, implementation

I trying to build and array with data for each ID, so I can read from it data by ID
so I implemented this thing:

```
for (var i in data.length) {

//data - XML response 
            var obj = {};
            /*setting al data
            obj.ID =parseNode(data[i], "ID");
            obj.year= parseNode(data[i], "year");
            object.model= parseNode(data[i], "model");
            ...
            ..
            */

            if (this.modelData[obj.ID] == null)
                this.modelData[obj.ID] = [];
            this.modelData[obj.ID].push(obj);
        }
```

as a result I'm getting array with a big lenght,in this example  745645364 (the MAX id) with object for each ID:

```
modelData[1]= object
modelData[745645364]= object
modelData[56]= object
```

and reading data like this:

```
var year = this.modelData[ID].year;
```

Is this the right thing to do? I think the idea having an array with 5 objects and `length` of 566456456 is bad....

Comment: Smells like `data` is a string. Have you checked that?

Comment: Ok, so have you checked, that javascript interprets it as an xml-doc? Try `console.log(typeof data)`. And your loop is not the proper way to handle xml-data.

Comment: The Data is not the issue here! It's XML,List... any kind of data. I'm parsing it without any problems, my question is how **saving it right** with a **reference** to ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object instead of an array. Doing this will avoid the use of a huge array with many empty indexes.

Comment: What you mean by "use an object"? I need a place where to save all this data for each ID

Comment: this.modelData = {} Then your code should be practically the same except for your test of the definition : this.modelData[obj.ID] === undefined instead of null

Comment: I am doing that in my function `this.modelData = {}`. cant see how I getting over the problem with a big length if the object stays the same

Comment: So, if your modelData is an object you don't have a "huge" array then. You have an object with some properties labeled after your ids and you access it by the [] operator instead of the pointed notation (because you don't know the name of those properties).

Comment: ogoo you mean using object literal {} and not array...agree with you!